# HTML & CSS Clickable Background Image

Tags: html, css

I've searched everywhere to see how to code a background image into a clickable link. I have found a couple of answers to my question but none of them work!!! HELP!

Comment: Do you have an example of anything you have tried? Can you provide a fiddle or a url to an attempt?

Comment: As it stands, this question is too vague. See [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You can edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this using the following CSS trick:

Create an  tag as normal and give it an id. You'll need for the custom css.

```
<a href="#" title="your title" id="clickable-background">Clickable Background</a>
```

Now the custom css for the `#clickable-background` div:

```
#clickable-background {
background-image:url(your-image-path);
background-size: 100% 100%;
display:block;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Don't forget to add 
`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to your css.

Give it a go and see if it does what you want. Don't forget to edit your-image-path.